# show unique images on ajax call using mysql rand()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, random

I'm fetching some images from the database using mysql rand() function. When I print my array it shows unique records with unique images.

Also it displays different images on refresh of the page. Now I want to avoid the manual refresh and refresh it using ajax after a particular interval.

This works as well, but it doesn't loop through all images in a sequence.
For example image1 appears again after second or third image on ajax call. Which I want to avoid and loop through all uniquely without repetition.

Like if my query fetches this :
image1
image2
image3
image4
image5

I want it to loop in the same order without any images getting repeated.
Currently images appear like this :
image4
image3
image1
image4
image2
...
...
....and so on.

So as you can see the images are not in sequence.

This is my code :

This is my file where the image are fetched and looped.

```
<?php 
        $club_activity_id = get_single_value("mpc_clubs","activity_id", "id =".$_SESSION['USERACTIVECLUB'],$orderby="1",$order="desc",$limit="",$disp=false);
        //echo $club_activity_id;
        $select_sponsor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mpc_sponsor_ad WHERE ( FIND_IN_SET('".$club_activity_id."',activity) or activity = '0') and status > 0 ORDER By RAND() limit 1");

            if(mysql_num_rows($select_sponsor) > 0)
        {
?>
<ul>
    <li class="content-menu" style="opacity: 1;" id="ad">


                <div class="content-menu_part width_175">
                    <?php
                        $fetch_sponsor = mysql_fetch_array($select_sponsor);
                        if ($fetch_sponsor['sponsor_ad_title']) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="content-menu-lf"><?= $fetch_sponsor['sponsor_ad_title'] ?></div>
                    <?php   
                        }
                    ?>
                    <div class="content-menu-rt"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="contete-txt" style="padding:0 0 0 0px; width:200px;">


         <?=stripslashes($fetch_sponsor['sponsor_ad_url'])?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

And this is the ajax call to refresh after 20 seconds on window load. This code is in the footer file and ajax is posted to right-sponsor.php that is the file above with the query.

```
$(window).load(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "common/right_sponsor.php",
    success:function(msg)
    { 
      $('#sponser').html(msg);
      //alert('yes image changes.!!');
    }
  });          
}, 20000);

});
```

Comment: Where exactly are you looping through the images, i dont see any `loop` construct in your php code

Comment: @dreamweiver I'm not actually looping just fetching one record at a time.

Comment: so that means the query on the server end itself repeating the images, need to improvise the query then.

Comment: @dreamweiver but the query thows unique records. I dont think so query needs to be changed. Or ????

Comment: actually the issue is with the `rand()` with `order by` only. **You cannot use a column with RAND() values in an ORDER BY clause, because ORDER BY would evaluate the column multiple times.** ref:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 0):

On page load generate a list of all images randomly, save this list (only the IDs) in your session and when you refresh it via ajax get them in normal order like 1 - 5, then 6 - 10, etc.

Comment: Even if store the Id in Session how will I pass it through ajax???. Ajax just refreshes the query and generates results one image at a time.

Comment: You have to rewrite you php file because the current process does not work. When calling the same php file via ajax you have to check if the image list was already generated and stored in session and you also need an offset variable to be sent which moves through the list.

Comment: this is what I tried with my code to check if the id is already set if set then do nothing and if different show that image. But it still doesn't work can you tell where I'm wrong. `<?php
     if($_SESSION['chk_id']==$fetch_sponsor['id']){

     }else{
    ?>
         <?php

          echo stripslashes($fetch_sponsor['sponsor_ad_url']);
          $_SESSION['chk_id'] = $fetch_sponsor['id'];
             }
         ?>` This is in my PHP file where I'm fetching the image and  just above that I'm checking the session. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It shows no image if the Id is present in the session. As you can see from the code above.